# scons/waf implementation that doesn't re-build upon cloning

Tags: git, scons, waf

Currently, I create a scons (or waf) build and run everything. Then I check *everything* (including .sconsign.dblite, etc) into git and push to the remote. If I delete the directory locally, clone it from git (on the same machine), and type `scons`, it treats everything as being built already and nothing is re-run.

However, if I do this on a different machine, scons/waf thinks everything needs to be re-run. I thought the advantage of these build tools was that they use hash's instead of time-stamps so I shouldn't have to re-run on different machines.

Two questions:

(1) What is forcing the rerun when you switch machines?

(2) Is there a way to prevent the re-run from occuring?

(In the waf lock file, I could see machine-specific details, but I didn't notice anything when I looked at the .sconsign.dblite file, though I just examined it in a txt editor.)

Comment: With SCons try running:  scons --debug=explain  it should tell you why it's rebuilding.  Then post the output..

Comment: First wild guess: a different machine might mean it's a different compiler (hash value of `gcc` changes) that's getting used...

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564403/how-do-i-tell-scons-to-ignore-implicit-dependencies-from-command-actions/11616078#11616078) fixed my problem. The issue was that scons was automatically tracking the hash/time-stamp of the executables used (such as 'Rscript'), which change across machines. Turning this implicit dependency check off fixed the issue.